# Converting a existing db schema to star schema

Tags: data-warehouse, star-schema

I am trying to use BI tools to do data analysis on a db that was not designed according to star schema model that the tools expect. Is there a way to convert existing db or atleast part of it say a few tables to star schema model?

Comment: How big is your database?  Could you just write some views that get the data into a star schema?

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways:

1. Create views (as already suggested) or use a 'metadata' layer (like a business objects universe or Cognos package) over the top to make it look like a star schema. This is horribly slow though.
2. Batch load it into a star schema warehouse

What is the business issue? Too slow? too difficult to work out what to join? Not enough built in business logic (KPI's, YTD's etc.) Star schemas solve both these problems, but method one is almost always slow and complex. Method 2 is much faster but possibly more complex to implement.

Comment: +1 for option 2.  Setup a DW/BI database with appropriate star-schema structure and ETL to update the DW from the operational database.